# Using Array from a fetch request that returns cors object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a simple API call that returns an array. I believe I am successfully making the call, but the data is in the form of a cors type response object and I can't figure out where the data actually is or how to access it.

```
var React = require('react');

fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', {
     method: 'get'
}).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

When I type the url into the browser, the first part of the array is like this: 
    [{"username":"sjames1958gm","img":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4639625?v=3","alltime":4401,"recent":528,"lastUpdate":"2016-12-06T16:10:35.053Z"},{"username":"diomed","img":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/72777?v=3","alltime":1524,"recent":482,"lastUpdate":"2016-12-03T21:57:45.952Z"},

So I assumed that I could do data[0].username but data[0] is undefined.

The actual object return looks a little like this: Response {type:cors, url:, status:, *proto*, etc}

Comment: `.then(response => response.json()).then(data => { ... })`. Fetch returns the promise resolved with a `Response` object.

Comment: Are you sure you're not logging the **error**? Your `console.log()` calls don't distinguish - it's a good idea to add some qualifier, like `console.log("data is ", data)`

Comment: Thanks zerkms that worked perfect! Pointy, I added that to the console.log to check and it was returning the response, but I'll keep that in mind for the future.